# Did Vegeta ever talk about the super saiyan 5 in Dragon Ball GT?

Tags: japanese-language, dragon-ball-gt

In this video [Vegeta talks about super saiyan 5](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QMkHS20LZNU) in Spanish Vegeta says

> Kakaroto, miserable, you can turn into super saiyan 4 or super saiyan
> 5, do what you want, I dont intend to stay with my arms folded

Did he say the same in the japanese version, or was this an invention of the spanish or western translations?

Did Vegeta ever talk about the super saiyan 5 in Dragon Ball GT?

Comment: The video has been taken down due to copyright claims. Can you find an alternative clip? And am I right in understanding that you're only referring to the Spanish dub?

Answer (score 1):

No, this was just yet another dub choice made by funimation, this line doesn't exist in the Japanese version. Super Saiyan 5 is no more real or canon than "Super Saiyan Infinity". Granted its probably the most well-known fan fiction form stemming from one of the most popular, and in opinion one of the best, pieces of Dragon Ball fanfiction

Comment: The question seems to be talking about the Spanish dub. Was Funimation responsible for the Spanish dub?

Comment: Oh, I didn't see the Spanish part, because even in the English dub Bulma mentions Super Saiyan 5, which was because of funimation

Comment: You meant "dub choice" or "dumb choice"?

Comment: Both work @Taladris

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for the short answer, no, Vegeta didn't talk about Super Saiyan 5